# Can ogr2ogr "reverse clip" (or "clip out" or "erase" or "difference") one shapefile from another?

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, clip, erase, differences

Is there a means in `ogr2ogr` to "clip out" one shapefile from another?

I know `ogr2ogr -clipsrc B.shp out.shp A.shp` will remove any part of `A.shp` that is NOT in `B.shp`.

Is there an ogr2ogr command to remove any part of `A.shp` that intersects with `B.shp`?

I have seen this called "reverse clip", "clip out", "erase" (ArcMap), or "difference".

**Note:** this question is about `ogr2ogr`, the command line tool, NOT the OGR library, which requires programming.

Comment: Is your copy of GDAL compiled with sqlite/spatialite support?

Comment: I don't believe so.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

`ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" out.shp road.shp \
  -dialect sqlite -sql "\
     select ST_Diffrence(road.geometry, seg_buff.geometry) \
     from road, 'seg_buff.shp'.seg_buff seg_buff \
  "`

Putting an extra `seg_buff` at the end makes the query work.

This extra word is needed because `ogr2ogr` only automatically generates SQL table names for files passed to it directly.  When specifying an additional file from within the SQL statement you must supply an arbitrary table name<sup>1</sup> to refer to it elsewhere in the SQL statement.  In this instance:

```
 The shapefile
 |             The table within the shapefile
 |             |        The name we're going to use to refer to the
 |             |        table elsewhere in the SQL statement
 |             |        |
 ------------  -------- --------
'seg_buff.shp'.seg_buff seg_buff
```

<sup>1</sup> The supplied table name doesn't have to match the filename (or its contained table).  For example, the following works as well:

`ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" out.shp road.shp \
  -dialect sqlite -sql "\
    select ST_Diffrence(road.geometry, foo.geometry) \
    from road, 'seg_buff.shp'.seg_buff foo \
  "`

In either example, `out.shp` will contain only the parts of `road.shp` that are not contained within `seg_buff.shp`.

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining why this might work or by providing citations.

Answer (score 2):

Using GDAL >= 1.10.0 compiled with SQLite and SpatiaLite:

```
ogr2ogr difference.shp a.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT ST_Difference(a.geometry, b.geometry) AS geometry FROM a, 'b.shp'.b"
```

Comment: It doesn't work in my case  ```ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" out.shp road.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "select ST_Diffrence(road.geometry, seg_buff.geometry) from road, 'seg_buff.shp'.seg_buff```  and this gives me ```no such column: seg_buff.geometry'``` I do not understand why this gives me that error

Comment: @PilKwon See my edit to Shadab's answer

Answer (score -1):

Try using this command:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc B.shp out.shp A.shp -clipsrclayer B
```

Comment: Could you please provide some extra explanations, citations or other useful information to make this answer better?

Comment: Apologies, I have misunderstood the question,

Comment: The answer for the question is to do a "Difference" operation which can be done in QGIS Python API, PostGIS. Also as explained by Shadab.