# Clipping rasters with GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, clip

I have this raster (land-and-water.tif):

[image]

And this one (land-only.tif, black = no data):

[image]

And I need this (black = no data):

[image]

I'm trying to do it with GDAL. Here's what I tried so far:

```
gdaltindex clipper.shp land-only.tif
gdalwarp -cutline clipper.shp -dstalpha land-and-water.tif water-only.tif
```

But the clipper.shp is empty, and obviously the resulting water-only.tif is the same as land-and-water.tif . I think I need to tell gdaltindex what is the no-data value in my land-only.tif , but I didn't find how in the doc.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

as far as I can estimate that, several processing steps would be neccesary to achieve what you are looking for. In a first step, you should preprocess your land-only raster and throw away any channels and pixel values, to be able to convert it to a simple extents-shapefile without killing your PC in a second step:

```
gdal_calc.py --calc=1 --outfile=land-only-extents.tif -A land-only.tif  
gdal_polygonize land-only-extents.tif land-only.shp
```

What you want, is the difference of land-only-extents and the extents of land-and-water.tif. The reason is, if you use gdal_warp with your land only extents like you proposed, you will get your land-only.tif – again. Therefore you also need the extents of your land-and-water.tif. If this is a rectangle, you can use gdaltindex as you already mentioned. If not, use the same process again. Having that, there exists the possibility to calculate the difference of both with ogr2ogr. [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151699/can-ogr2ogr-reverse-clip-or-clip-out-or-erase-or-difference-one-shapef) source indicates how to do that, and for your case it should look something like that (untested):

```
ogr2ogr difference.shp land-and-water.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT ST_Difference(land-and-water.geometry, land-only.geometry) AS geometry FROM land-and-water, 'land-only.shp'.land-only"
```

Some further information on ogr sql can be found [here](https://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html). This should give you a clipping layer that should work somehow like that:

```
gdalwarp -cutline difference.shp -dstalpha land-and-water.tif water-only.tif
```

If you think nodata-values might be a problem, or maybe have to fight with coordinate systems, you can always set that with gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs <source srid> -s_srs <dest srid> -a_nodata <nodata value> input_raster.tif output_raster.tif
```

Please let us know if that helped or worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I finally found a solution using Mapnik's compositing and a water shapefile from Natural Earth.