# OGR2OGR Differencing Vector Layer

Tags: ogr2ogr, erase

This is related to the link attached below and in my case, it is not working properly.

[Can ogr2ogr "reverse clip" (or "clip out" or "erase" or "difference") one shapefile from another?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151699/can-ogr2ogr-reverse-clip-or-clip-out-or-erase-or-difference-one-shapef)

From road.shp, I want to erase out where the road.shp intersects with seg.shp

```
ogr2ogr difference.shp road.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "Select ST_Diffrence(road.geometry, seg_buff.geometry) as geometry from road, 'seg_buff.shp'.seg_buff"
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(Select
>   ST_Diffrence(road.geometry, seg_buff.geometry) as geometry from road,
>   "_OGR_1"):   no such column: seg_buff.geometry

This is the road.shp screenshot and seg.shp screenshot together

road.shp
[image]

seg.shp
[image]

Comment: In your SQL you refer to `seg_buff.shp` and in your screenshots `seg.shp` - does `seg_buff.shp` exist?

Comment: As [@RoperMaps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/77948/ropermaps) suggested, can you try `ogr2ogr difference.shp road.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "Select ST_Diffrence(road.geometry, seg.geometry) as geometry from road, 'seg.shp'.seg"`. What does it say?

Comment: @Taras, RoperMaps, sorry there was a typo. Seg_buff.shp and seg.shp is basically same file. and of course, it gives me a same error message

Comment: Looks like it does not work on lines being differenced by polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited the script a little bit as below and it worked just fine.

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite out.shp input.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "select st_difference(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry from input as a, 'overlay.shp'.overlay as b"
```

this, however, is not working with same geometry type (i.e., difference line and polygon did not work with)

Answer (score 0):

If you play with layers and not with features you can use GDAL ogr layer algebra. See https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc39_ogr_layer_algebra and https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/LayerAlgebra.

You can find some Python examples from https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/attachment/wiki/rfc39_ogr_layer_algebra/layer_algebra.2.py.