# Get the same behaviour as the 'Difference tool' of QGIS, in ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, command-line

I have shapefile with lines, and another with polygons. I want to generate an output of those lines that are not covered by any polygon.

I can perfectly do this in QGIS's Difference tool, but want to do it with og2ogr.

I tried to do it, using the following command:

`ogr2ogr -overwrite out.shp line.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "select st_difference(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry from line as a, 'polygon.shp'.polygon as b"`

But it just generated a .dbf file.

This behaviour has also been reported here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/324837/442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDAL has a new script for Algebraic operations on Vectors called [ogr_layer_algebra.py](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr_layer_algebra.html#ogr-layer-algebra-py) which can be used instead.

An equivalent command would be:

`ogr_layer_algebra.py ERASE -input_ds line.shp -method_ds polygon.shp -output_ds output.shp`

Do note that is available only in newer versions (3.6 +) of GDAL.

Comment: It is exactly not so new script, it was already mentioned in one of the answers https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298855/ogr2ogr-differencing-vector-layer/324837 four years ago. But the script is easier to find nowadays, earlier users could get it only directly from GitHub.