How to clip a hole with ogr2ogr?
ogr2ogr has a rich set of clip options, e.g.,
-clipsrc [<xmin> <ymin> <xmax> <ymax>]|
   WKT|<datasource>|spat_extent

But how can I clip the same sized hole instead?

With SQL "ST_Difference" https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/151699/2856 https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=ogr2ogr+%22st_difference%22
